# React Redux Error: redux.js:275 Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'Promise'

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, dispatch

I am using redux along with a Material Table in order to add data to my database, however, my add function errors with "redux.js:275 Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'Promise'". I am using thunkmiddleware. Anyone know how to fix this?

```js
export const createActivity = (rowData) => async dispatch =>{
    const newActivity = {...rowData};
    const phaseRef = db.doc(`phase/${phaseId}`);
    newActivity.phase = phaseRef;

    const activityId = await api.createActivity(newActivity);

    dispatch({type:'ACTIVITY_CREATE_SUCCESS'})

    return activityId;
}
```

Comment: You have to return dispatch but you are returning activityId.

Answer (score 0):

The **async** and **await** must be inside the method **createActivity**. Simply put if you are using axios, the method must look like:

```js
const createActivity = async (url, data) => {
  return await axios.post(url, data).then(res => res.data);
};
```

Also in this code you can divide the url from the data to sent.

Comment: what if im not using axios?

Comment: It will be the same put the **await** before the method that makes the request.